# Inner HTML of ng-container, Angular 4?

Tags: html, angular

I want to dynamically place an html code in my html code, So I write the following code:

```
<ng-container [innerHTML]="buttonIcon"></ng-container>
```

Angular says `innerHTML` is not valid attribute for `ng-container`
I don't want to use third html tag like follows:

```
<div [innerHTML]="buttonIcon"></div>
```

So how can I insert html codes without any tag inner html binding?

Comment: What about `<ng-template ...`?

Comment: I've tested it, it throws the same error

Comment: <span> doesn't have any visual effect and accepts innerHTML

Comment: use [outerHTML] on the div and it will be replaced

Comment: @MichaelWestcott `ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use ngTemplate:

```
<ng-template #buttonIcon>
    <div> Your html</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container 
   *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonIcon">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: No its exactly what was requested. The div is just some example content. I like this solution alot!

Comment: The solution is fine, but I agree with @eugensunic, you are still using an extra div. What if you want to render JUST html content ([innerHTML] without ANY extra html? Sounds a little bit tricky as is not possible to use ng-container with innerHtml

Answer (score 33):

```
[outerHTML]
```

will do the trick to replace the outer element.

In your case

```
<div [outerHTML]="buttonIcon"></div>
```

It's true, that it's important to have a clean HTML structure for e.g. keeping CSS rules as simple as possible.

Comment: I encountered a problem with this approach.. I did this: `<div *ngFor="let html of contents" [outerHTML]="html"></div>` and every time `contents` changed Angular did not remove the previously added HTML tags from the page, instead it added more and more stuff to the page. The solution was to separate the `ngFor` from the `outerHTML` like this: `<div *ngFor="let html of contents"><div [outerHTML]="html"></div></div>`

Comment: Doesn't work for me because of `ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node`.

Answer (score 4):

** Please read the comments.  This answer might be wrong. I dont know, have not looked into it again **

`ng-container` does not get rendered to html, it is a mere [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue).

> The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular *doesn't put it in the DOM*.

So there is no element to put html into. You need to work with a sub-div. If there is no need for a sub-div in your opinion, then you could most probably also just replace `ng-container` with `div` itself and not use the container at all.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question since you are suggesting to add s sub-div ...

Comment: @eugen_sunic yes and I also explained why. `ng-container` can*not* have an innerHTML attr because it's not part of the DOM. You need to use another element instead, for example div.

Comment: Yes  but then you have an extra div or any other html element which has access to the innerHTML attribute encompassing/surrounding your html which you don't want...

Comment: how can you not want that? the innerhtml needs to be inside *something*. you cant put html into nothing

Comment: Yes, but let's say you have a page structure and a component which renders additional HTML onto this existing HTML, you want to avoid this extra div because it should not be there, it's unnecessary. I would go with a viewchild on ng container and then append the html to this viewchild id of the hidden component (ng-container)

Comment: "you would"? what does that mean? is it possible thiat way? aka `[ng-container].append(theHtml)`?

Comment: also, I disagree, that very div *should* be there. Angular cannot change the limitations of html. Imagine how you would do it without Angular. You would either use a parent-div or do something like `node.insertBefore(newNode)...`. Maybe that would be an idea for you

Comment: @Blauhirn NO! The whole purpose of `ng-container` is exactly TO put something into nothing, otherwise why does it even exist? This snippet: `<ng-container>something into nothing</ng-container>` adds the text to your page without any containing html element, but Angular can still track it if you wanted to change or hide it. So there's no reason why you couldn't make some kind of template outlet (like ng-container) that would allow `<ng-container [innerHTML]="something into nothing"></ng-container>`.

Comment: It should work. Inner HTML as a child, or innerHTML using the angular property, are the same everywhere else - why should ng-container be an exception?

Comment: @speciesUnknown Agree, except the attribute should probably be called simply "HTML" or "html" since there is no "inner" or "outer" in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't want to mess with the convention here, it has the role of an innerHtml.

Answer (score 2):

If for any reason you need to replace the DOM element you can use a div with an id and then use the **@ViewChild** decorator and **ElementRef** to get access to the nativeElement from the controller and set the **outerHtml** property.

**app.component.tml**

```
<div #iconButton></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit }from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent  implements AfterViewInit{
   @ViewChild('iconButton')
    iconButton: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.iconButton.nativeElement.outerHTML = '<button>My button</button>'
    }
}
```

We need to use none as encapsulation policy because our template only includes the div to be replaced.

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa1zwp