# Is there an Angular 2+ Equivalent to React Fragments?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, frontend, angular6

I would like to extract a portion of a component without actually creating an additional "wrapper" element in the physical DOM, because it breaks my CSS.

Example: I noticed a section in my HTML template that looks like this:

```
<div>Foo</div>
<div>Bar</div>
```

I want extract these two tags into a component called `<MyComponent>`, and reuse it in other places. However, when I don't actually want a parent component called `<MyComponent>` to be added to the DOM. Currently what I see rendered is

```
<MyComponent>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
</MyComponent>
```

React lets me solve this problem perfectly using the concept of a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) component, which lets you group elements without adding an additional node to the DOM.

I am wondering if there is a section of the Angular Component API that I'm missing that will let me do this, or it there's a fundamentally different way I should be thinking about reusing code within Angular Components.

This application is in Angular 6, and I'm coming from a background in React 16+.

Edited with Sample Code Snippet: I would like this to render without having a `hello` element added to the DOM - I only want the `<p>` tag inside the `hello` component to appear

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaxm27

Comment: Angular and React are very different in some ideas, can you post an example of what you need. you could use differnt solutions but they depend on the real use case

Comment: Edited to add a functioning code sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134604/2138752

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"ng-container" is an element that’s available in Angular 2+ and that can act as the host to structural directives.

```
<ng-container> 
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Related reading from Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really work if you wanted to reuse Foo/Bar from another component/file. Wherever you put it will still have the parent component's tags wrapped around the ng-container tag. I'm looking for a solution as well since I'm coming from React too...

Answer (score 4):

Usage `ng-container` with `ngFor` ( for ) loop and table tag.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
    </tr>
   <ng-container>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: '[my-fragment-component]',
  ...
})
export class MyFragmentComponent {}
```

...

```
<div my-fragment-component>
</div>
```

It will work, don't know of any possible side-effects...

Comment: The point is to make `ng-container` work as a component host. Currently, what happens if you try this is you get `ASSERTION ERROR: "ng-container" tags cannot be used as component hosts. Please use a different tag to activate the MyFragmentComponent component.`

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, this feature does not appear to be directly supported. Some commenters have indicated this is possible with the help of some low-level APIs, but I haven't found a working code sample yet.

There is an open feature request in the Angular Github repository with active discussion around figuring out how to add this for a future release (after Angular 6).

Further reading from the Github repository:

- [Components host-element should (optional) be a html-comment instead of html-element](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22208)
- [Feature Request: Fragments Components (like ng-container)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18877)

Comment: Have you thought about use a Directive instead of a Component? Can you please post a working code to show what you want achieve? 
In Angular you have to "think Angular". It's not always possible to map a React feature with an Angular one (or viceversa)

Comment: @MassimoCosta - I want to be able to reuse an arbitrary block of HTML without polluting the DOM with extra nodes. For example, I would like to make this code snippet work without adding the `hello` component to the DOM. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaxm27 . I'm not super familiar with Directives, any guidance on how that could help solve this is appreciated!