# how to dynamically generate components html code in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an angular component maker and i would like to be able to dynamically generate the HTML code for this component. I already tried this but I can't find a way to dynamically set the element type in the HTML code.

```js
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

export class BaseComponent<K extends HTMLElement> {
  public type: K;
  public classes: string[] = [];
  public style = {};
  public childNodes: BaseComponent<HTMLElement>[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'base-component',

  template: `
    <<my component.type here> [ngClass]="this.component.classes" [ngStyle]="this.component.style" ]>
      <base-component *ngFor="let child of component.childNodes" [component]="child"></base-component>
    </<my component.type here>>
  `
})
export class GraphicalComponent {
  @Input()
  public component: BaseComponent<HTMLElement>;
}
```

but yet I did not find any way to properly inject my k type element in the dom unless I use document.createElement function which doesn't really make sense in an angular reference based program

Comment: Go for `ngTemplate`and `ngTemplateOutlet` with content projection usin ngContent

Comment: this doesn't seem to solve my problem since i can not summon a custom element in the dom

Comment: I've tried using outerHTML property as suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134240/inner-html-of-ng-container-angular-4 , and I checked out ComponentFactoryResolver, but I still can't find out how to properly inject any HTML builtin or custom angular component in the dom